# Crashing on [AFHTTPRequestOperation error]; (AFNetworking)

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I'm getting a crash caused by `AFNetworking` at least that's where the stack trace (below) is pointing me. I've currently 457 crashes for this problem but this is small enough compared to the amount of users the app gets.

Version: 1.1.0. (I'm about 11 months out of date)

I've today updated to 1.3.3. Updating to 2.0 is on the cards but just bit bureaucracy to deal with.

The app is network based, generally making 4 calls concurrently on each view controller and every two minutes of being on the same VC I'll make the calls again. The calls are in an operationQueue and I do call cancelALLOperations where appropriate. In between the calls we update using sockets, to which we have our own implementation.

A VC can use imageWitUrl: for up to 20 images simultaneously. These are thumbnail sized images.

**My Questions**,

1. Has anyone dealt with smiler stack trace. Would you know reproducible steps to cause it?
2. I can't see from the commits, but would anyone know if its been resolved in latest version or in 2.0?
3. Do you think it could just be how I implement afnetowrking in my code?

I understand this isn't best question, especially as I'm so out of date but as the project has a large release cycle and I've no way to reproduce it I'd like advise of my peers.

I've found a closed issue on this but it doesn't mention a fix, https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1574

All the calls are AFJSONRequestOperation's, example of my standard call.

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *requestOperation   = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    // create our models and pass it back
    NSArray *results = [self parseBaseEventsWithDictionary:JSON andSort:NO];
    success (results);
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
     failure(error, response.statusCode, @"failure", JSON);
}];

return requestOperation;
```

**The exception**

```
SIGSEGV
SomeName -[AFHTTPRequestOperation error]
```

**The Stack Trace off the Testflight report I keep getting:**

> 0 SomeName    0x0022fdea  testflight_backtrace
>
> 1 SomeName    0x0022f47e  TFSignalHandler
>
> 2 libsystem_platform.dylib    0x38878062  _sigtramp
>
> **3   SomeName    0x0020d172  -[AFHTTPRequestOperation error]**
>
> 4 SomeName    0x0020eb46  __65-[AFImageRequestOperation
>   setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:]_block_invoke_2
>
> 5 libdispatch.dylib   0x38738d1a  _dispatch_call_block_and_release
>
> 6 libdispatch.dylib   0x3873e68e  _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke$VARIANT$mp
>
> 7 libdispatch.dylib   0x3873fd70  _dispatch_root_queue_drain
>
> 8 libdispatch.dylib   0x3873ff58  _dispatch_worker_thread2
>
> 9 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3887adbe  _pthread_wqthread
>
> 10 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3887ac83  start_wqthread

Comment: What is the actual error/exception?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out just updated the question, it's a SIGSEGV in [AFHTTPRequestOperation error].

Comment: OK, so what does this block/method do with `error`? `failure(error, response.statusCode, @"failure", JSON);`

Comment: In general we show a popover depending on the responseStatusCode.

Comment: Sorry further looking shows that error.localizedDescription  is passed to the popover. It would also be logged with TFLog on to testflight, on this crash I doesn't get logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Has anyone dealt with smiler stack trace. Would you know reproducible steps to cause it?
>
> I can't see from the commits, but would anyone know if its been resolved in latest version or in 2.0?

I can't find the exact issue, but I have a pretty strong recollection that this was fixed way before 2.0 was released (and way after 1.1.0.)

> Do you think it could just be how I implement AFNetworking in my code?

I don't think so, unless you modified the library directly.  An NSError object is created, stored, and passed back in the completion handler.  Nothing too complex.

In summary: I would assume updating to 1.3.3 fixed this, unless you find information to the contrary.